# Cambiar el formato de la fecha que recibo de AAAA-MM-DD a DD/MM/AAAA

Tags: javascript, date

En esta función, de la *Base de Datos* traigo el valor de fecha en formato `AAAA-MM-DD`, y lo que quiero es que al recibir por AJAX se cambie el formato de fecha a `DD/MM/AAAA`.

Si alguien como hacerlo sin necesidad de usar PHP para lograrlo sería de gran ayuda.

```js
function asignar_variables_formulario_editar_pedido(co_id_compra) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>co_compras/getCompra',
    data: 'co_id_compra=' + co_id_compra,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(resp) {
      $(".ed_fecha_pago_promesa").val(resp.co_fecha_pago_promesa);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Espero que me pueda dar entender, en esta funcion que realizo de la base de datos traigo el valor de fecha que es 2017-01-10, y lo que quiero es que en ajax cambiar el formato de fecha a 10/01/2017, si alguien como hacerlo sin necesidad de usar php para lograrlo serían de gran ayuda

Comment: Checa esto te puede servir http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882935/formatting-a-date-string-in-javascript

Comment: @CesarVieyra puedes editar tu pregunta [aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/43768/edit) si deseas agregar más información.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solución usando expresiones regulares

```js
var texto = '2017-01-10';
var salida = formato(texto);
console.log(salida);

/**
 * Convierte un texto de la forma 2017-01-10 a la forma
 * 10/01/2017
 *
 * @param {string} texto Texto de la forma 2017-01-10
 * @return {string} texto de la forma 10/01/2017
 *
 */
function formato(texto){
  return texto.replace(/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$/g,'$3/$2/$1');
}
```

Answer (score 9):

una forma mas elegante puede ser esta...

```
   function convertDateFormat(string) {
        var info = string.split('-').reverse().join('/');
        return info;
   }
```

Comment: Está genial, yo siempre lo hago así, pero con una pequeña diferencia. JavaScript pesa menos cuanto menos código metas en el archivo (es lógico), así que yo pondría mejor: `return string.split("-").reverse().join("/");` y te ahorrarás el crear una variable nueva que va a ocupar espacio (en este tipo de ejercicios no se ve una grandísima diferencia pero cuando desarrollas algo más potente si se puede notar la diferencia entre una función y otra) pero lo digo de nuevo, está genial.

Answer (score 4):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- Obtener los datos de la fecha (eg: *día, mes, año*) separando la cadena por el separado `-` y luego armar la fecha en el orden deseado.

  Así por ejemplo:

```js
var dateString = '2017-01-10';
console.log(convertDateFormat(dateString));

// @param string (string) : Fecha en formato YYYY-MM-DD
// @return (string)       : Fecha en formato DD/MM/YYYY
function convertDateFormat(string) {
  var info = string.split('-');
  return info[2] + '/' + info[1] + '/' + info[0];
}
```

- O podrías usar una `lib`, por ejemplo, [`momentjs`](http://momentjs.com/)

```js
var dateString = '2017-01-10';
console.log(moment(dateString).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Gracias Marcos, utilice la libreria y funciono de maravilla fuiste de gran ayuda

Answer (score 2):

```
diaActual = new Date();

var day = diaActual.getDate();
var month = diaActual.getMonth()+1;
var year = diaActual.getFullYear();

fecha  = year + '' + month + '' + day;
```

O lo acomodas como gustes... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Muy buenas opciones, o también con expresión regular para fechas con guion `-` o  slash `/`:

```
fechaYyyymmdd.split(/[-/]/).reverse().join("-");
```

Comment: y que hace tu código???