# Formatear fecha en javascript

Tags: javascript, date

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente, tengo dos fechas que recibo de dos ***input type date*** 12/01/2019 cuando las envió por **ajax** al  controlador me da *NULL* si hago un `var_dump` tendría que  formatearlas en el script a 2019-01-12... Creo que seria la solución pero no se como hacerlo..

Gracias Adjunto código de la función que rellena la tabla enviando los datos por **ajax**.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function convertDateFormat(string) {
  var info = string.split('-');
  return info[0] + '-' + info[1] + '-' + info[2];
}

  function listar(){



    var id_area = document.getElementById("idarea").value;
    var fechah = document.getElementById("Fechahasta").value;
    var fechad = document.getElementById("Fechadesde").value;
    convertDateFormat(fechad);
    convertDateFormat(fechah);





    if (fechad > fechah  || fechah == '' || fechad == '' ){
      alertify.alert("Atención","Rango de fechas incorrectos");
      return false;
    }
    else{

      $("#titulo").show();
      $("#movimiento").show();
      var combo = document.getElementById('area').value;

      document.getElementById("ctexto").innerHTML='Listado de entradas de productos'+'-'+combo;
      // fechah = Date.parse(fechah).toString("yyyy-MM-dd");
      // fechad = Date.parse(fechad).toString("yyyy-MM-dd");

      var table = $("#movimiento").DataTable({




           "serverSide":true,

        "ajax": {
          "type": "POST",
          "url":baseurl+"reportes/creporte/getent",
          "data":"id_area="+id_area+"&fechah="+fechah+"&fechad="+fechad,
          //   "data": function (d) {
          //   return $.extend({}, d, {
          //     "id_area": $("#idarea").val(),
          //     "fechah": $("#Fechahasta").val(),
          //     "fechad": $("#Fechadesde").val()
          //   });
          // }
        },
        });
    }

  }


</script>
```

//En el controlador tengo el siguiente código

```
public function getent() {
    //$id_area = $this->session->userdata('s_id_area');
    //$fechah = $this->input->post('Fechahasta');
    //$fechad = $this->input->post('Fechadesde');
    //$fechah = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $fechah)));
    //$fechad = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $fechad)));
     $fechad = $this->input->post("fechad");
     $fechah = $this->input->post("fechah");
     $id_area = $this->input->post("id_area");
    var_dump($fechad);
    var_dump($fechah);
    //$id_area = $this->input->post('idarea');
    // $fechah = $fechah->format('Y-m-d');
    // $fechad = $fechad->format('Y-m-d');
    var_dump($id_area);

    $requestData = $_REQUEST;

    $valid_columns = array(
        0 => 'id',
        1 => 'name',
        2 => 'cant',
        3 => 'fecha',
        4 => 'receptor',
        5 => 'usuario',
        6 => 'remito',
        6 => 'expediente',
    );

    $sql = "SELECT entradas.id_entrada as id, productos.name as name, entradas.cantidad_ent as cant, entradas.date_ent as fecha, entradas.receptor as receptor, usuarios.user as usuario, entradas.remito_ent as remito, productos.nro_expediente as expediente  from entradas, productos, usuarios where date(entradas.date_ent) between '$fechad' and '$fechah' and entradas.id_area='$id_area' and productos.id_producto= entradas.id_producto and usuarios.Id_usuario= entradas.id_user";
    $query = $this->mreportes->query($sql);
    $totalData = count($query);
    $totalFiltered = $totalData;

    // define column for searching
    if (!empty($requestData['search']['value'])) {
        $sql .= " AND (  name LIKE '" . $requestData['search']['value'] . "%' ";
        $sql .= " OR  receptor LIKE '" . $requestData['search']['value'] . "%' )";
    }
    $query = $this->mreportes->query($sql);
    $totalFiltered = count($query);

    //ordering clause //by default  0th coloumn asc
    $sql .= " ORDER BY " . $valid_columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']] . "   " . $requestData['order'][0]['dir'] . "   LIMIT " . $requestData['start'] . " ," . $requestData['length'] . "   "; // adding length
    $query = $this->mreportes->query($sql);

    $data = array();

    $cnt = $requestData['start'] + 1;
    foreach ($query as $dt) {
        $nestedData = array();
        $nestedData['rowId'] = $dt['id'];
        $nestedData[] = $cnt++;
        $nestedData[] = $dt['name'];
        $nestedData[] = $dt['cant'];
        $nestedData[] = $dt['fecha'];
        $nestedData[] = $dt['receptor'];
        $nestedData[] = $dt['usuario'];
        $nestedData[] = $dt['remito'];
        $data[] = $nestedData;
    }

    //create json in datatable form
    $json_data = array(
        "draw" => intval($requestData['draw']),
        "recordsTotal" => intval($totalData),
        "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalFiltered),
        "data" => $data,
    );

    echo json_encode($json_data);

}
```

Comment: Saludos, revisa si [éste enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43768/cambiar-el-formato-de-la-fecha-que-recibo-de-aaaa-mm-dd-a-dd-mm-aaaa/61755) realiza lo que necesitas ;)

Comment: Hola Israel como puedo formatear las variables fechah y fechad

Comment: Vi el enlace pero no entiendo como hacerlo en la misma función listar sin necesidad de crear otra función, ya que debe hacerlo  dentro de la función listar()

Comment: lo hice console.log(fechad) me trae la fecha invertida pero cuando hago un var_dump ($fechad) del lado del controlador me da NULL

Comment: Edite el código porque me sigue recibiendo NULL en el controlador el envío de las variables desde la vista con  ajax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es que estás enviando mal los parámetros vía Ajax.

Se tendrían que enviar así:

```
$.ajax({
    "type": "POST",
    "url":baseurl+"reportes/creporte/getent",
    "data": {"id_area": id_area, "fechah": fechah, "fechad": fechad}
});
```

Comment: Gracias Ferran!!